# Going from an 8 sided dice to a 10 sided

Tags: classical-mechanics, dice

I considered what would happen if you shaved two opposite corners off a d8 dice (Octahedral)

The result of which would be as so
[image]

How much should be removed from the corner for it to be fair?

I think there are probably quite a lot of factors going on. An initial guess would be to make the areas of each face equal. But it would probably be better to ensure each face has the same equivalent area when projected onto a circle from the centre.

Are there any good models that include some mechanics for things like center of mass, intertia etc.

disclaimer: I no nothing about dice mechanics....

Comment: I don't think this is a mathematics question.

Comment: This is a _really_ difficult question, and I don't think humanity knows an answer (search for "three-sided coin" for a similar problem: how thick must a coin be for it to be a fair three-way toss between heads, tails, and standing on the edge). Also, I suspect that the answer depends on things like how bouncy the die is on the surface where it's being thrown, and throwing technique (how much spin you put into it, how high you throw it and so on). So I don't think there is a good answer to this.

Comment: A selection of research papers on the topic would satisfy as an answer but unfortunately I couldn't find any from a search. Hence why I need help from mathematicians who know the field etc.

Comment: @MatthewDaly That's actually not entirely accurate. Most 10-sided dice are not constructed from pentagonal pyramids. If you look closely at one, you can see that the faces are in fact kites (quadrilaterals with two pairs of adjacent, equal length sides), not triangles.

Comment: @Arthur Whoops, you're right.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_trapezohedron My point was that dice considered "fair" are made from faces that are congruent and would also have a rotational symmetry so that the solid angles would also be congruent.  Without that, you're into the "quite a lot of factors" that would make the dice unfair under at least some real-world trials.

Answer (score 3):

Not only this is very difficult question, it's also ill-defined. I would argue, that if you managed to make this die fair for a specific material of the die/surface, it's possible to alter one of those to make the die unfair again.

In other words, the answer will be different for different physical models of the dice throwing.

Having said that, there is a particular setup which allows for easy fairness calculation. That is when the die is not bouncy at all (inelastic collision). In that case, when it lands on a vertex or an edge, the face that intersects with a gravity ray from its center of mass will be the face on which it will fall after. In other words, we want for all faces to have the same solid angles (if seen from center).

Take initial octahedron with side 1.
If the square face of a new die has side $d$, then the distance from center is $s=\frac{1-d}{\sqrt2}$ and solid angle:
$$
\Omega_1(d)=\int\limits_{-d}^{d}\int\limits_{-d}^{d}\frac{s\ dx\,dy}{(s^2+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}
$$

For a trapezoid face the math is a little harder. With $h=1/\sqrt6$ the distance from the center to the face in octahedron:
$$
\Omega_2(d) = \int\limits_{-\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}}^{\frac{2-3d}{2\sqrt{3}}}\int\limits_{-\frac13+\frac{x}{\sqrt3}}^{\frac13-\frac{x}{\sqrt3}} \frac{h}{(h^2+x^2+y^2)}dy\, dx
$$

Numerical calculation of $\Omega_1(d)=\Omega_2(d)$ gives $d=0.343866$

Comment: This is definitely a good starting point. 
The ill-definition lies in the difficulty of it. Is the elasticity of the bounce was increased, would there be a way of modelling the likely end face given a starting inertia and starting face? Could Markov chains modelling a "face transition matrix" help?

Comment: It is trickier than simple markov chain. However, using physical kinetics language, one can define an evolution function for a probability function over state space "angle-angular velocity" at the moment of collision. This evolution function is contracting in a sense that on the infinity there will be only 10 nonzero states. By discretizing the initial space, we can get the markov chain problem. However, discretization should be very fine, as this is essentially  a dynamical chaos problem. Two very close initial states are likely to resolve in two different final states.

Comment: In practice, instead of using markov chain, it's easier to build a physical engine and simulate the result many times.